# How to rename column of single column DataFrame in R

Tags: r

I have a list of single column dataframes. The dataframes have all the same rows and I would like to change the value of the single column to the name of the dataframe (Index in list).

So I wrote a function:

```
change_colname <- function(df_list) {
  name_vector <- names(df_list)
  for (i in length(name_vector)) {
    working_name = toString(name_vector[i])
    working_df = df_list[i]
    colnames(working_df) <- working_name
  }
}
```

This returns:

```
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = working_name) : 
attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```

Well, then I read about single column dataframes, that they are a problem in R and thought I could transpose the dataframe.

```
df_list <- lapply(df_list, function(x){t(x)})
df_list <- lapply(df_list, data.frame)
```

Changed the function accordingly:

```
change_rowname <- function(df_list) {
  name_vector <- names(df_list)
  for (i in length(name_vector)) {
    working_name = toString(name_vector[i])
    working_df = df_list[i]
    rownames(working_df) <- working_name
  }
}
```

This returns:

```
Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = working_name) : 
attempt to set 'rownames' on an object with no dimensions
```

However something must be wrong in my function, since when I try in the console:

```
dim(df_list$df)
```

It returns:

```
[1] 96  1
```

and for the transposed:

```
[1]  1 96
```

Hence written in the function:

```
print(dim(working_df))
```

it returns:

```
NULL
```

but:

```
print(working_df)
```

returns the entire dataframe.

Does anybody know what is the problem here?

Thanks in advance and best regards
Lukas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `mapply`:

```
df_list <- list(df1 = data.frame(x = seq_len(3)), df2 = data.frame(x = seq_len(4)))
df_list_renamed <- mapply(setNames, object = df_list, nm = names(df_list), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

In this context also see [this article](https://win-vector.com/2018/02/27/r-tip-use-drop-false-with-data-frames/) on `drop = FALSE` with data.frames.